# DropDown is getting opened for every other button in the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. Here, I have a table , in which there are more that 20 elements are there. So, there are 20 td's.
Now,

```
<tbody className="text-center" ref={props.refer}>
  {props.isRowAddingEditorVisible && <RowAddingEditor removeRow={props.removeRow} />}
  {props.jobList && props.jobList && props.jobList.length > 0 && props.jobList.map((item, key) => {
    return (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" name={item.jdName} checked={!!props.parentState[item.jdName]} onChange={props.handleTableCheckboxChange} />
        </td>
        <td>{item.technology}</td>
        <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.jdIdScore ? item.jdIdScore.resumeCount : 0}</td>
        <td title={item.jdName} className="jd-name-container justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div className="jdName">{item.jdName}</div>
          {(item.isNew) && <div className="badge new-badge badge-warning-custom">New</div>}
        </td>
        <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.jdIdScore ? item.jdIdScore.totalFinalScore : 0}</td>
        <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.jdIdScore ? item.jdIdScore.jdAverage : 0}</td>
        <td>
          <JobActionsButton />
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })}
</tbody>
```

Now, Here there is one component that is

```
<JobActionsButton />
```

which actually is like this .

```
import React from "react";

export default class NewCollapse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    };
  }
  enableQuiz = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: true,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  };
  enableView = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: true,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  };

  enableUpload = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: true
    });
  };

  render() {

    const btnHeight = {
      height: "100%",
      background: "rgb(87, 160, 245)",
      borderRadius: "2px"
    };

    return (
      <div id="mainmenu">
        <div className="list-group panel">
          <button
            href="#menupos1"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-parent="#mainmenu"
            style={btnHeight}
          >
            Quick Action
              <span className="menu-ico-collapse">
              <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
            </span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse pos-absolute" id="menupos1">
            <span
              href="#submenu1"
              onClick={this.enableQuiz}
              className={
                this.state.quizEnable
                  ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                  : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
              }
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-parent="#submenu1"
              aria-expanded={this.state.quizEnable}
            >
              Quiz
                <span class=" menu-ico-collapse">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
              </span>
            </span>
            <div
              className={
                this.state.quizEnable
                  ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                  : "collapse list-group-submenu"
              }
              id="submenu1"
            >
              <a
                href="#"
                class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu1"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Create New</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="#"
                class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu1"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">View</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="#"
                class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu1"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Update</label>
              </a>
            </div>
            <span
              href="#submenu2"
              onClick={this.enableView}
              className={
                this.state.viewEnable
                  ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                  : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
              }
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-parent="#submenu2"
              aria-expanded={this.state.viewEnable}
            >
              View
                <span className=" menu-ico-collapse">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
              </span>
            </span>
            <div
              className={
                this.state.viewEnable
                  ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                  : "collapse list-group-submenu"
              }
              id="submenu2"
            >
              <a
                href="/"
                className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu2"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Job Description</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="/"
                className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu2"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
              </a>
            </div>
            <span
              href="#submenu3"
              onClick={this.enableUpload}
              className={
                this.state.uploadEnable
                  ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                  : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
              }
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-parent="#submenu3"
              aria-expanded={this.state.uploadEnable}
            >
              Upload
                <span className=" menu-ico-collapse">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
              </span>
            </span>
            <div
              className={
                this.state.uploadEnable
                  ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                  : "collapse list-group-submenu"
              }
              id="submenu3"
            >
              <a
                href="/"
                className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu3"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Folder</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="/"
                className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                data-parent="#submenu3"
              >
                <img
                  className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                />
                <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
              </a>
            </div>
            <a
              href="/"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#menupos1"
              className="list-group-item sub-item"
            >
              <img src="" className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
              <label className="list-component">Download Tracker</label>
            </a>
            <a
              href="/"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#menupos1"
              className="list-group-item sub-item"
            >
              <img src="" className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
              <label className="list-component">Selection Criteria</label>
            </a>
            <a
              href="/"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#menupos1"
              className="list-group-item sub-item"
            >
              <img src="" className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
              <label className="list-component">Remove</label>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, In this there is one button on click of this button it gets open .
But what is happening currently is that `on click of a single td button others are also getting opend` .

So, I actually getting confused why is this happeing ? can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Why are you talking about `react-redux`? I see no `redux` in your code.

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake. I have just removed that

Comment: Thank you :)
Also there are a lot of buttons and a tags in `JobActionsButton` ON what element you are actually clicking?

Comment: the first one which has a name quick-action.

Comment: `<button href="#menupos1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainmenu" style={btnHeight}>` has no react handlers. I suspect you are catching click event with some other tool.
if you want to handle click event with react you should do something like this:
`<button onClick={() => {console.log('Hello')}}>`

Comment: what I see is that you use and re-use the same html ids in all your copies of the component. This is the problem. It opens or closes based on id but all use exactly the same id

Comment: No, actually the thing is on click of that it should have open that div so, I am doing that

Comment: If you want to "open" div on click you should add another property to state `this.state = {dropEnable: false}` add handler `enableDrop = () => {this.setState({dropEnable: true})}` and use that handler instead like this: `<button onClick={this.enableDrop}}>`

Comment: What about the id's that @NikosM. is saying about

Comment: Unless you are using third party library to handle that logic (And I would suggest you not to do that). But if you wish to use it anyway you should use different id's on your `<JobActionsButton/>` as ganesh kaspate said: `<JobActionsButton id={key}/>` and after that `<div id={"mainmenu" + this.props.id}>` and `<button data-parent={"#mainmenu" + this.props.id}   >`

Comment: I have used exactly same but still it is giving me the same behaviousr.

Comment: Actually I am totally new to this , So it would be really helpful if you post as an answer, as I have done the required changes but it is not working.

Comment: could u please a react way ?